# Надо ли ставить запятые между обстоятельствами?

Tags: пунктуация

Есть предложение:

Познакомился поверхностно(,) во время еженедельной проработки информации(,) и тогда не заказал ее для более серьезного изучения.

Нужно ли здесь выделять обстоятельства "поверхностно" и "во время еженедельной проработки информации" запятыми?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Познакомился поверхностно, во время еженедельной проработки информации, 
и тогда не заказал ее для более серьезного изучения.

Обстоятельства раскрывают одну тему, отношения однородные или пояснительные. С учетом структуры предложения лучше считать их пояснительными.